# Identity theft from ubuntu machine?

Tags: unix, identity-theft

Recently my debit card information went to another hand, and he/she started to using it until my bank reports that there is an overdraft. I use Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

I am sure I am not a victim of phishing, or email-scam. But I sometime use debit card for online purchases.

Moreover, after going through my account history, I have noticed that these unauthorized transactions occurred just a couple of days after a taxi ride, where I had to pay with my debit card.

And during the same time I just started to explore the Tor network.

I do not have any firewall.

what could be the reason? Any idea?

Comment: have you considered that the taxi driver stole your debit information and is using it?

Answer (score 1):

You describe three possible attack vectors in your post:

1. Payment details stolen from an online service.
2. Taxi driver recording and using your debit card information.
3. Payment information stolen from your computer.

Of the three, I'd rank having it stolen from your computer as the least likely.  There's very little Linux malware, and most of it is focused around taking over computers and using them as servers/botnet nodes, rather than the typical Windows malware that tries to steal financial or account information.

Comment: Or _4. Payment details stolen during network transmission (lack of TLS, MitM, etc.)_ (which is neither `1.` nor `3.`)

Comment: To be honest though, if the Ubuntu box is misconfigured (ssh open, weak passwords), it may be compromised and a keylogger installed.